# How to store a PDFDocument fast?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit

Problem1 : I have a PDF document containing 1300 pages. Users are able to add and remove pages from it. If I want to store the new PDF Document I have to convert it to data with (.dataRepresentation() ). This takes about 10 seconds which is way to long (What if the user terminates the app).

Solution: Split the document in 1300 PDF's, each one containing 1 page. Store this PDF inside an array called var pages = Data. Users can now add and remove new Pages from this array easily. I don't have to call .dataRepresentation() anymore.

Problem 2: When I use this method i have a new problem. The memory for this array is very huge. About 400mb. The PDF document itself is only 46mb.

How can i solve this problem ? Is there maybe another way ? Please help me out i can't find any solutions :(

Comment: On second problem, you could load only the pages when needed, and deallocated them on the go.

Comment: The document will be stored permanently on the device